# Geo location notification in iOS

Tags: ios, core-location, uilocalnotification

I want implement a geo location notification in iOS, but just in a specific date and time.

The notification will only be launched if the user is in a certain location and at a certain date and time.

Ex.: The user is in Rio de Janeiro and is 12 o'clock.

Does anyone know how to merge these two conditions to launch a notification?

Comment: Do you want this to fire when your App is running, or even when it's closed ?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in that I know of -- you will have to code the logic yourself. So you will simply get geo updates from CoreLocation, and you can create a timer to give you time updates, then write some logic that execs periodically and, if the time/place matches your business rules, fire the notification. Note that the app will have to be running to accomplish this. You could send a push notification from an external server, but that server must know where the phone is, and your app must tell it.

Does this help?

Comment: I think it can be more simple, I will search more about this. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this can be done elegantly as long as location updates are given precedent.

Use this CoreLocation [startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion%3adesiredAccuracy%3a)

To get updates about location, and these updates will be able to start your app in the background (as explained in the docs). Then, in the "application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method of your AppDelegate, include your logic for checking if it is the right time to send a notification (by checking with stuff in CoreData or otherwise).

There shouldn't be a need to create a timer with periodic checks. Just let CoreLocation handle the event's entry point since it'll launch your app in the background at the right location.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. I assume that you are familiar using the `CLLocationManager` and the `MKReverseGeocoder` classes. For your purpose monitoring for only significant location changes would probably be fine (even if that sometimes only happens for moving kilometers). It will help you save battery power on the device.

So, for `CLLocationManager's` delegate there is a method called `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation` what you can use. All you need to do is to use reverse geocoding here to determine the actual city's name depending the actual location using the `MKReverseGeocoder` class. Also, you have to check the local time on the device, match the two, and act accordingly (set up a local notification to wake the app from the background for example).

Comment: I don't think this would work when the user was already in the correct location, when the time changed to a valid time.?

Comment: Actually Rory I have to say you are right! Good thinking. :)
We have to extend upon what I said above and whenever a significant location change happens, we have to store the new location's city probably to **NSUserDefaults**. Also we need to set up a local notification for 12 o'clock. When the local notification shoots off we can check the saved location and if it is matching to Rio de Janeiro, then display it, otherwise cancel (and set up a new one for the very next day).
Thanks for your comment, Rory!